# How to add a new item into ObjectListView?

Tags: objectlistview

I tried the demo code in demo project but I can't add new item successfully.
It just add new new NULL group and NULL item.
Please give me an simple example code to add new item (text and image).

Thank you!

---

Oh sorry! I forgot it. This is the first time I participate in this site.
I use C#. And the code is:

```
objectListView1.BeginUpdate();
objectListView1.AddObject(new string [] {"Hello","dfdsF" });
objectListView1.EndUpdate();
```

and

```
objectListView1.BeginUpdate();
OLVListItem item = new OLVListItem(new string [] {"Hello","dfdsF" });
objectListView1.Items.Add(item);
objectListView1.EndUpdate();
```

It's so different form ListView and EXListView which I can define a text or a image when creating new item. But in ObjectListView, I don't understand OBJECT?

I get ObjectListView anh it's demo code form here http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/objectlistview/objectlistview/v2.5/ObjectListViewFull-2.5.0.zip

Comment: What language is this in? What is the source code for the demo project? We need substantially more information in order to help you. Please review the FAQ for tips on how to ask questions here.

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot it. I use C#. 
And the code is:

objectListView1.BeginUpdate();
objectListView1.AddObject(new string [] {"Dfdf","dfdsF" });
objectListView1.EndUpdate();

I got the demo example form: http://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/files/latest/download

Comment: Your best bet is to review the detailed getting started documentation that is provided for this control: [Getting Started](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html#gettingstarted) There are also more in-depth questions and answers here: [Learning to cook](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#cookbook) And a detailed tutorial on CodeProject: [A Much Easier to Use ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx)

Answer (score 26):

I will show you what to do to add items. Try to create a class, then make getters and setters for the properties you want to show on your `ObjectListView`.

`SetObjects` method takes a `List<T>`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.objectListView1.SetObjects(haha.GET());
}
```

Now this is my class, I called it `haha`, I've two properties in it (`Name` and `Detail`):

```
class haha
{
    string name;
    string detail;
    public haha(string name , string detail)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public string Detail
    {
        get { return detail; }
        set { detail = value; }
    } 

    static internal List<haha> GET()
    {
        haha item = new haha("zeko", "dunno");
        haha xx = new haha("sheshe", "dunno");
        haha ww = new haha("murhaf", "dunno");
        haha qq = new haha("soz", "dunno");
        haha ee = new haha("HELLO", "dunno");
        List<haha> x = new List<haha>();
        x.Add(item);
        x.Add(xx);
        x.Add(ww);
        x.Add(qq);
        x.Add(ee);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Now

- change `ShowGroups` in `ObjectListView` to false
- then add the columns that you want; I've added two columns, one for `Name` and one for `Detail`
- and as in the picture when you add a column, see the `AspectName` and write exactly the same name of its property that you want to show from your class

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

If you want to use `AddObject()`, which takes an object, I'd write this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    haha newObject = new haha("memo","zezo");
    objectListView1.AddObject(newObject);
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use an entity class. Then make a list of items and add this list to your `ObjectListView`.

```
myObjectListView.SetObjects(myListofEntityItems);
```

But before you do that, you have to setup the columns in your designer. Just add a column, and in the field `AspectName` enter the exact name of the attribute of your entity item.