# Unable To Cast Object error when trying to populate ObjectListView control

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

I have downloaded the ObjectListView.dll and added it as a reference into my VB.NET application.  I have added it to my toolbox and added an ObjectListView control to my form.  However, when I try and populate it, I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to
>   type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListItem'

My code snippet looks like so:

```
lsvOverdueCalls.Items.Add(tempDT.Rows(0)("id").ToString)
lsvOverdueCalls.Items(0).SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(0)("summary").ToString)
lsvOverdueCalls.Items(0).SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(0)("first_name").ToString)
```

Unsure if I'm doing something wrong.  My applicaton is compiled under the full version of dot.net 4.5, not the client version as advised.
Any help appreciated.

**Update**
I noticed I get the following error in my debugger window but ONLY when moving the mouse over a ListViewItem:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
>   occurred in ObjectListView.dll System.Transactions Critical: 0 :
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled
>   exceptionDrakeMon2.0.vshost.exeSystem.InvalidCastException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Unable to cast
>   object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to type
>   'BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListItem'.   at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.GetItem(Int32 index)    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.LowLevelHitTest(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OlvHitTest(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.BuildCellEvent(CellEventArgs
>   args, Point location)    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;
>   msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   DrakeMon2.frmNewDashboard.ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Dropbox\VS Projects\DrakeMon v2.0\DrakeMon
>   v2.0\frmNewDashboard.vb:line 986    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m,
>   MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;
>   msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at DrakeMon2.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in
>   17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.InvalidCastException:
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to
>   type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListItem'.    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.GetItem(Int32 index)    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.LowLevelHitTest(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OlvHitTest(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.BuildCellEvent(CellEventArgs
>   args, Point location)    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;
>   msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   DrakeMon2.frmNewDashboard.ToolStripMenuItem2_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Dropbox\VS Projects\DrakeMon v2.0\DrakeMon
>   v2.0\frmNewDashboard.vb:line 986    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp; m,
>   MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&amp; m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message&amp; m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;
>   msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)    at DrakeMon2.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in
>   17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I'm assuming a threading issue, but I'm unsure why this control throws an error and a normal listview or even the BetterListView control doesn't.  My form only contains this control and nothing else.  And...like mentioned, it ONLY occurs if I try and move the mouse over a ListViewItem.

Thanks

Comment: I dont think it works with ListViewItems...you need to read the docs...see section 2.2: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do `Add()` on the `ObjectListView` like you do on a normal `ListView`. Instead, you need to call the `SetObjects` method on the `ObjectListView` instance, and pass it a list of items to add.

So in your case, create a `List<Call>` of the items to add (assuming your model is a `Call` class with `id`, `summary` and `first_name` fields, and then pass it on to the `lsvOverdueCalls.SetObjects()` like so.

```
var lstCalls = new List<Call>() 
                      { 
                        new Call() { 
                                     Id = tempDT.Rows(0)("id").ToString,
                                     Summary = tempDT.Rows(0)("summary").ToString,
                                     First_Name = tempDT.Rows(0)("first_name").ToString 
                                   }
                      };

lsvOverdueCalls.SetObjects(lstCalls);
```

And here's how your `Call` model should look like.

```
public class Call
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shiva.  I have converted your code to VB and have the following: Dim lstCalls = New List(Of [Call_Details])() From {New [Call_Details]() With {.Id = tempDT.Rows(x)("id").ToString, .Summary = tempDT.Rows(x)("summary").ToString, .First_Name = tempDT.Rows(x)("first_name").ToString}}
                    lsvOverdueCalls.SetObjects(lstCalls).  This now removes all of my errors however, my ObjectListView is now empty.  I can see that my lstCalls has data in it.

Comment: Okay fixed thanks to this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949887/how-to-add-a-new-item-into-objectlistview) I wasn't adding the AspectName details to my ObjectListView control.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Sorry I forgot the question was in VB.NET :)